# Python urllib request not same as clicking in browser

Tags: python, html, https, urllib, wireshark

I need some help...

I'm trying to get some code to do some virtual clicking for me with urllib, and also using some wireshark but it just won't work. Here is some relevant code...

Python Code:

```
import urllib.request
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'heroeswow_hash=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'))
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'hw_page=vote'))
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'PHPSESSID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'))
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', '__cfduid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'))
opener.addheaders.append(('Cookie', 'rmm_wcw=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'))

f = opener.open("https://heroes-wow.com/execute.php?take=vote&site=11")

print(f.read())
```

HTML Button code:

```
<li>
    <a href="execute.php?take=vote&amp;site=11" onclick="window.open('http://www.gowonda.com/vote.php?server_id=4956', '_newtab'); return true;">
    <div class="vote-site-image" style="background-image:url('https://heroes-wow.com/mop/template/style/images/gowonda.gif')"></div>
    <p>You can vote now!</p>
    </a>
</li>
```

My understanding of the html code is that on a click, the web server executes a php "script" and also just opens a window. The

```
"<a href="execute.php?take=vote&amp;site=11" onclick="window.open ..."
```

should not matter at all.

If I manually click the button, it says that I've voted and I don't even have do do anything on the "gowonda.com" site.

Comment: Please elaborate on "it just won't work".

Comment: The thing I'm trying to do is a bot (this code is just for the action part) that will send a "vote". If I click the button on my browser it says "you voted", when I say "it just won't work" I mean that when I refresh my browser after running the code, it doesn't say that I've already voted.

Comment: No one that can help me? :/